# Push associated variables into array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a loop and each time the loop runs I need to add two variables to an array. What I am trying right now is:

```
$attach_array['outline'] = array();

foreach ($_POST['attachment'] as $key => $value) {
  $attachmentName        = $value['name'];
  $path                  = "1";
  $name                  = "alsdkjf";
  $attach_array['outline']['path']=$path;
  $attach_array['outline']['name']=$name;
}
```

Then later in the script I try to get these values out for PHPMAILER:

```
foreach ($attach_array['outline'] as $key => $value) {
   $mail->AddAttachment($value['path'], $value['name']);
}
```

This and other attempts are not working so I'm hoping for some help on putting $name and $path into an array in my first loop to use later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overriding the same variables on each loop. You should do something like this:

```
  $attach_array['outline'][] = array('path' => $path, 'name' => $name);
```

By doing this, now all the path and values will remain on the array as separate items. *You dont have to change the code you are using it from.*